# simulating a mobile phone

Tags: java, java-me, ios-simulator, emulation, simulator

considering we have a `Java Application` , is there  any plug which simulates the environment of a phone?

Comment: there are plenty emulators, for example **Java ME Platform SDK** ([see SO tag wiki here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-micro-editon-sdk3.0/info)) and **Wireless Toolkit** ([see SO tag wiki here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wtk/info))

Answer (score 3):

NO. J2ME has a different JVM which is a stripped down version of standard JVM, so many of the classes would not run on J2ME.

Comment: how about any plug in that simulate a phone device?

Comment: there are different emulators included in the SDK : http://java.sun.com/javame/sdk/.  You may also find more customized emulators in the SDKs released by the different device manufacturers.

Comment: yes, you can download J2ME plug-in for eclipse or netbeans, but you will have to write a different application or adapt your existing java application to J2ME. More about J2ME : http://java.sun.com/j2me/learning/index.html

Comment: @zahreelay netbeans has a J2ME project part already, no need to add any plug in, but considering he answer, it seems it doesnt match, so how about a plug in to simulate it for me?

Comment: your java application has to be rewritten to run on j2me.

Comment: @Grims how about to name some of them?

Comment: @user1064929 : how about google -> jme <manufacturer> sdk ? just to name some : [nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/) [sony](http://developer.sonymobile.com/cws/devworld/search-downloads/docstools/java/sdk) [samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=3&cateId=3&cntsId=&imgType=&searchText=sdk&sortType=0&codeType=All&nacode=uk&indexDirection=1&indexType=1&listLines=10&tabNum=1)